# Gravity forms phone field validation function to disallow numbers starting with "8"?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm receiving a lot of unwanted spam on my website coming from my gravity forms. I've tried all kinds of captcha, honeypot and anti-spam meassures to no avail. Now i want my forms to validate the "phone number" field, and disallow all entries starting with the number "8", as 90% of the spam i experience is being sumbitted with phone numbers starting with "8".

I tried following these steps (see part "7.") but it won't work on my live site. It still let's entries pass, no matter wether the phone number entry starts with "8" or not:

https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_field_validation/?_ga=2.46354080.606115829.1655889554-161403595.1654699851#h-6-phone-field-validation

This is the ammended .php snippet i've created so far, but as mentioned it has no effect:

```
// Block entries where phone numbers starts with "8" in form 24

add_filter( 'gform_field_validation_24', 'validate_phone_no_eight_at_beginning', 10, 4 );
function validate_phone_no_one( $result, $value, $form, $field ) {
    if ( $field->type == 'phone' && $field->phoneFormat == 'standard' && $value[1] === '8' ) {
        $result['is_valid'] = false;
        $result['message']  = 'Error.';
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Can anybody point me in the direction of what's wrong here? I have a hard time seeing why this won't do the job.

Thanks.

Comment: `$value[1] === '8'` compares _second_ phone digit with 8, because in PHP everything starts from 0

Comment: So this "$value[0] === '8'" should do the trick?

Comment: I just did. Now something happened at least. But it's blocking all entries into the form!?

Answer (score 0):

Damn! It works now. I forgot to change "validate_phone_no_one" straigh after "function" to match the add_filter part ('**validate_phone_no_eight_at_beginning**'). *Facepalm*.